Scalable Vertex Interpolation
so I am creating a procedural grass blade generator with the goal of making it scalable. I am running into the problem that when I add more geometry it simple overlaps the vertices as cant find a way to set the position of the new vertices with it staying scallable. I have a setup the can move the first center and last columns of vertices but I cant use that for anything else as it wouldn't be scalable. Essentially what I am looking for is a way to set vertices at an interpolated position between the center column and the outmost columns.
What Happens:


What I Want:
Node Setup:

Can you post some images or something explaining what you've done/ what you're aiming for? You'll be a lot more likely to get help if you don't make "downloading the entire Blendfile" the only way to understand your problem.

@Jakemoyo Fixed

So your goal is to add additional subdivisions running along the length of each grass blade?

@Jakemoyo essentially yes

Looking at your GN tree I think you can achieve this by going about the same technique in a slightly different way. This is a simplified version of the same concept you're doing.

Rather than trying to manually set the position of each vert in the profile curve after the fact, set it's extent in the initial creation of the Curve Line.
Like this:

This allows you to control the number of subdivisions very easily.
Then after than you can just get the current X-position of the vertex, subtract that from (0,0,0) to get its offset and then multiply that over your factor from the float curve node to achieve the taper effect.

Final result.

